# How to draw triangle as legend in R?

Tags: r, legend

I'm working on a plot where I need to draw legends and I require one of them to be a triangle.

```
  plot.new()
  legend(x=.5,y=.9, c("A","B","C","D"), cex=.8, bty="n", 
         fill = c("green","yellow","red","blue"))
```

I would like `legend D` to be *triangle in shape*. How can I implement this?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pch` and `col` (instead of `fill`):

```
plot.new()
legend(x=.5,y=.9, c("A","B","C","D"), cex=.8, bty="n",
       col=c("green", "yellow", "red", "blue"), pch=c(15, 15, 15, 17))
```

Comment: How can increase the size of legends?

Comment: Use the `cex` and/or `pt.cex` argument (character expansion factor)

Answer (score 2):

The pch parameter selects the shape of the legend symbol:

```
     plot.new();

     legend(x=.5,y=.9, c("A","B","C","D"), 
            pch=c(1,4,3,2), cex=.8, bty="n",
            col=c("green","yellow","red","blue"))
```

Comment: Thanks! But triangle is hollow. How to fill color.

Comment: the symbol number 17 will give you a filled triangle, so just replace the 2 in the pch parameter with 17

Comment: `?points` will give you all the possible point shapes you can get with `pch`.